# How to upgrade SQL query from SQL Server 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want a CRM that uses SQL Server as its database; I found [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/tustena/activity/?page=0&limit=100#56f2338234309d21facf9a44) - is there a better choice?

I compiled `Tustena.csproj` file but I get an error (i.e a reference to a null object), so I want to create database but SQL queries are old.

```
CREATE DATABASE [TustenaOS]  
ON (NAME = N'Tustena_Data', FILENAME = N'{0}\TustenaOS.mdf', SIZE = 3, FILEGROWTH = 10%) 
   LOG ON (NAME = N'Tustena_Log', FILENAME = N'{1}\TustenaOS_log.ldf', SIZE = 3, MAXSIZE = 2146, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'autoclose', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'bulkcopy', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'trunc. log', N'true'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'torn page detection', N'true'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'read only', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'dbo use', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'single', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'autoshrink', N'true'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'ANSI null default', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'recursive triggers', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'ANSI nulls', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'concat null yields null', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'cursor close on commit', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'default to local cursor', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'quoted identifier', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'ANSI warnings', N'false'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'auto create statistics', N'true'
GO

exec sp_dboption N'TustenaOS', N'auto update statistics', N'true'
GO

use [TustenaOS]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACTIVITYMOVELOG] 
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [ACID] [bigint] NOT NULL ,
    [ACTIONTYPE] [tinyint] NOT NULL ,
    [PREVVALUE] [nvarchar] (500) NULL ,
    [NEXTVALUE] [nvarchar] (500) NULL ,
    [MOVEDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [OWNERID] [bigint] NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have this query in SQL Server 2008, what is the equivalent in SQL Server 2012?

How to upgrade SQL query from SQL Server 2008 to 2012?

**Update**: I installed SQL Server2008 and run the query but I get this error for first line

> Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '{0}\TustenaOS.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>
> Msg 15010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dboption, Line 64
>   The database 'TustenaOS' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.

**Update 2**: Thank you Jeroen Mostert,  now in this line I replaced this

```
'   ON (NAME = N'Tustena_Data', FILENAME =N'{0}\TustenaOS.mdf', SIZE = 3, FILEGROWTH = 10%) LOG ON (NAME =N'Tustena_Log', FILENAME = N'{1}\TustenaOS_log.ldf', SIZE = 3, MAXSIZE =2146, FILEGROWTH = 10%) GO'
```

with this

```
'CREATE DATABASE [TustenaOS]'
```

but now in this line

```
    INSERT [TUSTENA_DATA] ([COMPANYNAME], [LICENCE], [PHONE], [FAX], [EMAIL], [WEBSITE], [ADDRESS], [CITY], [PROVINCE], [REGION], [STATE], [ZIPCODE], [ACTIVE], [MAXUSER], [ADMINGROUPID], [PHONENORMALIZE], [CUSTOMTYPES], [LASTACCESS], [TAXIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER], [VATID], [ESTIMATEDDATEDAYS], [DEBUGMODE], [FROMWEB], [GUID], [PIN], [DEFAULTWEBUSER], [IDAGENDA], [DATASTORAGECAPACITY], [SMSCREDIT], [SMSORIGIN], [LINKFORVOIP], [INTERNATIONALPREFIX], [DISKSPACE]) VALUES ('Tustena Custom Company', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', getdate(), 1, 20, 1, NULL, 0, getdate(), '', '', 90, 1, NULL, 'e30df889-6390-4dff-ba54-5d9137c4757d', 99999, 1, NULL, 20, 9, NULL, 'test://', '', 30 )
```

I have this error:

> Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'TUSTENA_DATA' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: There is not difference.

Comment: whar error u are getting

Comment: marc_c thank you for your edit

Comment: What's that `{0}` doing there in the error message? Looks like someone forgot to pass the script through a `String.Format` call somewhere. If your instance is configured correctly with default values for the database path and autogrowth, you can get away with just `CREATE DATABASE [TustenaOS]`. All the options being set are uncontroversial defaults; they should not need to be included in the script.

Comment: there is no answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The physical file name '{0}\TustenaOS.mdf' may be incorrect

Yes it is incorrect - you used C# formatting string directly in SQL Server management studio - that cannot work. You should provide correct path without `{0}` or `{1}`.

`db_option` stored procedure [is deprecated in SQL Server 2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27879/sp-dboption-is-not-available-in-sql-server-2012).

If you want to [insert into an identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql), you need to run:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[tableName] ON
INSERT ... -- insert identity values
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[tableName] OFF
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23101127/2224701).

Please do not keep adding multiple questions into one original question.

Answer (score 0):

db_option is not available in SQL Server 2012.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fc18f418-7285-4c1a-89af-9f20b023ac2c/alternate-option-for-spdboption-in-sqlserver-2012?forum=sqldatabaseengine

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27879/sp-dboption-is-not-available-in-sql-server-2012

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql

Comment: i found nothing